# Keycloak 20.0.0 with NginX

Tags: nginx, keycloak, reverse-proxy

Im using keycloak version 20.0.0 in my application. There I want to run keycloak on Nginx, I configure reverse proxy as follows

```
   location /auth {
            proxy_hide_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin;
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
                 proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
          }
```

Keycloak run as http://0.0.0.0:8080 and http://localhost:8080.

But when I access localhost/auth it gives me an error

[keycloak error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zqOT.png)

What can I do to make it run on keycloack and access keycloak through localhost/auth

Comment: Do you start keycloak with parameter  --http-relative-path=/auth

Comment: yes we did add /auth as relative path

Comment: And are there entries in your nginx-log file? Are you running in a docker environment?